# ChildBrowser Phonegap not working

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

After searching for a suitable way to open a browser within my app, i came across ChildBrowser, which looked like it offered everything I was after. After following a few tutorials, i cannot seem to get the plugin to work. I have edited my PhoneGap.plist file for external hosts with a value of "*", I have added in the plugins the ChildBrowserCommand, but when ever i run the application, nothing happens when i click the link. I have the following code in the head of my document;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var childBrowser;

    function onBodyLoad ()
    {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    //Phonegap ready to go
    function onDeviceReady()
    {
        alert("PhoneGap is ready");
        childBrowser = ChildBrowser.install();
    }

    function openChildBrowser(url)
    {
        try {
            window.plugins.childBrowser.ShowWebPage(url);
            //childBrowser.showWebPage(url);
        }
        cathc(err)
        {
            alert(err);
        }
    }

</script>
```

I have the ChildBrowser included straight after my phoneGap.js file but cannot seem to get it to run and i get no errors logged in the console. Does anyone know what is wrong or at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: i have a test project which uses facebook with childbrowser, you can check it for reference here https://github.com/dhavaln/phonegap-facebook

Comment: make sure `<plugin name="ChildBrowser" value="com.phonegap.plugins.childBrowser.ChildBrowser"/>` is defined in the `/res/xml/plugins.xml`

Comment: Thanks for the comments @dhaval. i do not have a plugins.xml file which leads me to believe that this may be the problem. However, i do not have a `/res/xml...` folder. When i create the file do i put it in the root of my www folder?

Comment: Android project from Eclipse already has `/res` folder you just need to create `/xml` and copy the required xml files. `/res/xml` goes in the root of the project and not in the `/www`

Comment: @dvaval, i am using ios project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours/days chasing many confusing pages on the topic, I finally found a concise set of instructions in this [blog page](http://blog.digitalbackcountry.com/2012/03/installing-the-childbrowser-plugin-for-ios-with-phonegapcordova-1-5/). Be sure to grab the latest code as shown in this [github page](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser). I was successful in getting the ChildBrowser plugin to work with PhoneGap 1.5.0 in Xcode 4.3 running in OSX 10.7.3 - and tested in iOS 4 and 5. Limitation I discovered is that it only works in portrait mode. I am now pursuing a resolution to include landscape mode.

Answer (score 3):

This code below works for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My External Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>

    <!--iPhone on Safari Standalone mode-->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

    <!--Hide iPhone on Safari Native Top Status Bar-->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="childbrowser.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", loaded, false);

        function loaded()
        {
            if (console)
            {
                console.log("cordova loaded");
            }
        }

        function showExternalPage()
        {
            if (console)
            {
                console.log("in show pmt page");
            }

            Cordova.exec("ChildBrowserCommand.showWebPage", "http://www.google.com/" );
        }

        </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="myExternalLauncherPage" data-theme="a">

        <div data-role="content">

            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">

                <li>
                    <button type="submit" data-theme="b" id="launcherButton" onclick="showExternalPage()">Launch Google</button>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

My partner wrote a step-by-step tutorial for adding the ChildBrowser plug-in to a PhoneGap Android project [here](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt3p2).

Comment: thanks for the link, but i am trying to get it working on an iphone/ipad

Comment: OK, I added an ios tag to your question. Good luck!